# Tangent line parallel to Y-axis, of a function $f(y)=\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}+x$ and points where tangent line does not exist

Tags: derivatives

I have function defines as :

$$f(y)=\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}+x$$

and need to find points where the tangent line is parallel to y-axis and point where tangent line does not exist. 
I found points where derivation is infinity [0,1], which should be the points where tangent line is parallel to y-axis. But i have problems to determinate how to find points where tangent line does not exist.
Any advices?

Comment: take the derivative of the function and see where is the derivative function undefined.

Comment: that is in 0 and 1, but how do i know if tangent line exist?

Comment: if tangent line exists at a point $x_0$ then that point would be a defined in $dom(\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right))$,e.g. $x_0 ∈ D_ {f'(x)}$ in your example tangent line does exist at $\left(-∞,+∞\right)-\left\{0,1\right\}$

Comment: excuse me but iam not really sure what does it mean

Comment: tell me what is unclear for you

Comment: Well, does it mean that in every point of function there is a tangent line, except 1 and 0, and x=0 and x=1 are parallel to y-axis?

Comment: I've added some notes in my post, look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}+x\right)=\frac{2x-3x^{2}}{3\sqrt[3]{\left(x^{2}-x^{3}\right)^{2}}}+1$$

clearly the function is undefined for $x=0,1$

Using limit definition for derivatives we have:

$$f'_{+}\left(0\right)=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x-0}$$$$=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}+x\right)-0}{x-0}$$$$=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}+x\right)}{x}$$$$=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x}-1}+1\right)}{x}=1+\sqrt[3]{\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}-1}=+∞$$
also for the other side we have:
$$f'_{-}\left(0\right)=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x-0}$$$$=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}+x\right)-0}{x-0}$$$$=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}+x\right)}{x}$$$$=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x}-1}+1\right)}{x}=1+\sqrt[3]{\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{1}{x}-1}=-∞$$

do the same for $x=1$ and you will see that the tangent line at these two points is parallel to vertical axis.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it´s clear to me.

Comment: @janerosie, if this answered your question so mark it, then it is not going to be in the unanswered question section